# ClickOnce Deployment in .net framework 2.0

Tags: clickonce, desktop-application

I am developing a window based application in .net framework 2.0.And I want to deploy it using click once deployment.How can I create desktop shortcut for my application?

And I also want to know that where will my application generated text files get saved after deployment.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

As for the Desktop shortcut: This can not be done automatically with the "older" versions. In Visual Studio 2010 there's a check box in the deployment properties. Even worse: When you create the shortcut manually, it will be removed after a ClickOnce update. However, I'm not sure whether this is a matter of the .NET Framework you use or the Visual Studio you use. Could well be that deploying a  .NET 2.0 project using Visual Studio 2010 also allows you to automatically create a shortcut. I haven't tried. I just know it doesn't work with VS 2005 and VS 2008.

As for the application generated text files: The framework picks a folder for that automatically, which resides somewhere in the Application Data folder of your user's profile. There's a lot of work involved finding out where it is.

Advice: Create a sub-folder in the user's Documents folder where you store your stuff, or create your own folder within the user's profile.